# Cannot read property 'find' of undefined, dexie async await

Tags: javascript, reactjs, async-await, асинхронность

Проблема возникает из-за того, что получение данных из бд происходит медленно, без async\await получается, что чтение из бд слишком медленное.

В `componentWillMount()` вылезает ошибка Cannot read property 'find' of undefined, потому что `getfieldsets()` не успевает отработать к этому времени (как я понимаю)

```
async function fieldsetsWork(){
    //объявление переменных
    var k=0;
    var string = '';
    var def = getFields().map((it,i)=>({
            name:it.name,
            hidden: false,}));
    var stringDef ='';
    for (var i=0;i<def.length;i++){
        stringDef = stringDef + def[i].name;
    }
    // проверка на существование филдсетов пользователя
    var pushDbUser = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(function(element){
                if (element.f_Uname.includes(global.currentUser.value.login.toString())){
                    fieldsets_.push(element);
                    k++;
                }});
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
        } finally { return 0; }
    })

    await pushDbUser().catch(e => console.error(e));


    // проверка версии
    if (k !== 0){
        for (var i=0;i<fieldsets_[0].data.length;i++){
        string = string +fieldsets_[0].data[i].name; }
        if (string == stringDef){ k = k;
        }else k = 0;
    }; 
    await console.log(k);
    // если нет филдсетов добавляем дефолтные
    var pushFDB = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(element =>{
            console.log(element)
                if (element.f_Uname.includes('default')){
                fieldsets_.push(element);
                console.log(element);
            }})
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null2',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
            yield console.log('0');
        } finally { return 0; }
    })
    if (k===0){
        await console.log('k=0')
        await pushFDB().catch(e => console.error(e));
        }
    await localStorage.setItem('requirements_fieldsets', JSON.stringify(fieldsets_))
    var p = await fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
        fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
    fieldsets =  p;
     return  fieldsets_;
}
fieldsetsWork();


export function getFieldsets(force){
    if(force){
        const fieldsets_ = fieldsetsWork(); //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('requirements_fieldsets'));
        fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
            fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
        fieldsets = fieldsets_
    }
    return fieldsets
}



componentWillMount(){
        this.setState(old=>({
            ...old,
            fieldset: getFieldsets().find(it=>it.favourite)
        }));
    }
```

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как вернуть значение из события или из функции обратного вызова? Или хотя бы дождаться их окончания](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/554290/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b2%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%bd%d1%83%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b7%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%81%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%8b%d1%82%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d0%b8%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b8%d0%b7-%d1%84%d1%83%d0%bd%d0%ba%d1%86%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%82%d0%bd%d0%be%d0%b3%d0%be-%d0%b2%d1%8b%d0%b7%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%98%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d1%85%d0%be%d1%82%d1%8f-%d0%b1%d1%8b-%d0%b4%d0%be%d0%b6)

Comment: А где у вас вызывается `getFieldsets` с параметром `true`?

Comment: @StepanKasyanenko здесь не вызывается, но `getFieldsets` возвращает `fieldsets`, которые присваиваются в `fieldsetsWork()`, я просто не знаю, как заставить остальную часть программы ждать, пока выполнится `fieldsetsWork()`, единственный вариант, который вижу, это записывать результат в state и перерендерить, когда результат придёт.

Comment: Можно вызвать `await fieldsetsWork();` тогда остальной код будет "ждать", пока не выполнится `fieldsetsWork`.

Answer (score 1):

У вас есть два варианта, при данной структуре организации кода.

Вызвать `await fieldsetsWork()`. Тогда остальная часть кода не будет выполняться, будет ожидать. На самом деле не очень хороший вариант.

```
async function fieldsetsWork(){
    //объявление переменных
    var k=0;
    var string = '';
    var def = getFields().map((it,i)=>({
            name:it.name,
            hidden: false,}));
    var stringDef ='';
    for (var i=0;i<def.length;i++){
        stringDef = stringDef + def[i].name;
    }
    // проверка на существование филдсетов пользователя
    var pushDbUser = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(function(element){
                if (element.f_Uname.includes(global.currentUser.value.login.toString())){
                    fieldsets_.push(element);
                    k++;
                }});
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
        } finally { return 0; }
    })

    await pushDbUser().catch(e => console.error(e));


    // проверка версии
    if (k !== 0){
        for (var i=0;i<fieldsets_[0].data.length;i++){
        string = string +fieldsets_[0].data[i].name; }
        if (string == stringDef){ k = k;
        }else k = 0;
    }; 
    await console.log(k);
    // если нет филдсетов добавляем дефолтные
    var pushFDB = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(element =>{
            console.log(element)
                if (element.f_Uname.includes('default')){
                fieldsets_.push(element);
                console.log(element);
            }})
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null2',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
            yield console.log('0');
        } finally { return 0; }
    })
    if (k===0){
        await console.log('k=0')
        await pushFDB().catch(e => console.error(e));
        }
    await localStorage.setItem('requirements_fieldsets', JSON.stringify(fieldsets_))
    var p = await fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
        fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
    fieldsets =  p;
     return  fieldsets_;
}
await fieldsetsWork();


export function getFieldsets(force){
    if(force){
        const fieldsets_ = fieldsetsWork(); //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('requirements_fieldsets'));
        fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
            fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
        fieldsets = fieldsets_
    }
    return fieldsets
}



componentWillMount(){
        this.setState(old=>({
            ...old,
            fieldset: getFieldsets().find(it=>it.favourite)
        }));
    }
```

Есть другой вариант, получше. Не вызывать отдельно `fieldsetsWork`, а запустить `getFieldsets` с  параметром `force=true`. Также переделать `fieldsetsWork` на асинхронную.

```
async function fieldsetsWork(){
    //объявление переменных
    var k=0;
    var string = '';
    var def = getFields().map((it,i)=>({
            name:it.name,
            hidden: false,}));
    var stringDef ='';
    for (var i=0;i<def.length;i++){
        stringDef = stringDef + def[i].name;
    }
    // проверка на существование филдсетов пользователя
    var pushDbUser = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(function(element){
                if (element.f_Uname.includes(global.currentUser.value.login.toString())){
                    fieldsets_.push(element);
                    k++;
                }});
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
        } finally { return 0; }
    })

    await pushDbUser().catch(e => console.error(e));


    // проверка версии
    if (k !== 0){
        for (var i=0;i<fieldsets_[0].data.length;i++){
        string = string +fieldsets_[0].data[i].name; }
        if (string == stringDef){ k = k;
        }else k = 0;
    }; 
    await console.log(k);
    // если нет филдсетов добавляем дефолтные
    var pushFDB = Dexie.async(function* (){
        try {
            var p = yield db.table('fieldsets').each(element =>{
            console.log(element)
                if (element.f_Uname.includes('default')){
                fieldsets_.push(element);
                console.log(element);
            }})
            yield p;
            yield console.log('null2',fieldsets_);
            yield console.log(fieldsets_[0]);
            yield console.log('0');
        } finally { return 0; }
    })
    if (k===0){
        await console.log('k=0')
        await pushFDB().catch(e => console.error(e));
        }
    await localStorage.setItem('requirements_fieldsets', JSON.stringify(fieldsets_))
    var p = await fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
        fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
    fieldsets =  p;
     return  fieldsets_;
}
fieldsetsWork();


export async function getFieldsets(force){
    if(force){
        const fieldsets_ = await fieldsetsWork(); //JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('requirements_fieldsets'));
        fieldsets_.forEach(fieldset=>
            fieldset.data.forEach(field=> field.def = getFields().find(it=> it.name===field.name)));
        fieldsets = fieldsets_
    }
    return fieldsets
}



componentWillMount(){
        this.setState(old=>({
            ...old,
            fieldset: await getFieldsets(true).find(it=>it.favourite)
        }));
    }
```

Comment: в первом случае `await fieldsetsWork()` выдаёт ошибку, надо что-то импортить дополнительно, чтобы `await` работал?

второй случай проверяю

Comment: @IvanBurilichev Так вы же `await` уже везде используете. Или не вы этот код писали?

Comment: частично я, но await не везде используется, то есть такой await, который предлагаете написать вы, будет лежать в компоненте, а не в функции

Comment: @IvanBurilichev И в чем проблема? Вы приведенные примеры пробовали?

Comment: В случае `await fieldsetsWork()` выдаёт `Parsing error: await is a reserved word`
А во втором случае, когда `await` рядом с `getFieldsets().find(it=>it.favourite)` тоже выдаёт `Parsing error: await is a reserved word`

Если убрать из `componentWillMount()`  `await`, то просто выдаёт `Object(...)(...).find is not a function`

Comment: @IvanBurilichev в таком случае показывайте полный пример.